# Expected annual returns (financial maths)

Tags: expectation, finance, economics

An economy contains these three assets:

Asset A has standard deviation of returns (per annum) of 25% and market capitalisation $600m

Asset B has standard deviation of 20%, market capitalisation $300m

Asset C has standard deviation of 10%, maket capitalisation $100m

The correlation coefficient for the returns on each pair of distinct securities is 0.25.

The risk-free rate of return is 3.3% per annum and the expected return on the market is 8.38% per annum.

The assumptions underlying CAPM are valid and all investors will hold their portfolios for the next year.

How can I calculate the expected annual returns for each asset?

Comment: Please share your own efforts on this problem (besides copying it from your homework assignment and pasting it here).

Comment: Hint: The expected return for asset A is $25\%\cdot \$600m=\$150m$